# Python Write to Influx V1.8+

Tags: python, influxdb-python

I have implemented a python script to import data to some influx databases.
The data is written as line protocol.
One instance of influx is v2.7, the write of data works, so I guess my line protocol data is O.K.

The other instance of influx is v.1.8.10. I can connect, create a database, switch to that database, but the write always fails with "Bad request"

```
"POST /write HTTP/1.1 " 400 28
```

When I do it by hand using the following curl command

```
 curl -i -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8086/write?db=testdb' --data-binary 'measurement,tag1=first,tag2=second raw=1i,physical=1.0 1699436519000'
```

I get as response

```
"POST /write?db=testdb HTTP/1.1 " 204 0
```

I have actually no clue, what the problem is.

Here is my implementation of the client for writing to the database

```
''' Client for influxDB1. '''
import logging
import json

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

class Influx1Writer:
    ''' Client to access influxDB1. '''

    def __init__(self, dbname) -> None:
        ''' Initializer, will be called from constructor. '''
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + __class__.__name__)
        self.host = ''
        self.port = ''
        self.user = ''
        self.password = ''
        self.usessl = False

        try:
            with open('influx_1_secret.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
                content = json.load(fin)
                self.host = content['host']
                self.port = content['port']
                self.user = content['user']
                self.password = content['password']

            if not self.host:
                self.logger.error('file influx_1_secret.json, must contain an "host" element')
                return

            if not self.port:
                self.logger.error('file influx_1_secret.json must contain a "port" element')
                return

            if not self.user:
                self.logger.error('file influx_1_secret.json must contain an "user" element')
                return

            if not self.password:
                self.logger.error('file influx_1_secret.json must contain an "password" element')
                return

            self.client = InfluxDBClient(
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port,
                username=self.user,
                password=self.password,
                database=dbname,
                ssl=self.usessl)
            # create database in case it does not exists, otherwise influx will do nothing
            self.client.create_database(dbname)
            self.client.switch_database(dbname)
            self.client.switch_user(self.user, self.password)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.logger.error('file influx_1_secret.json not found')

    def write(self, records) -> None:
        ''' Write a batch of records to influxDB V1. '''
        if records:
            self.logger.info('.write: Amount of records is %s', len(records))
            response = self.client.write(data=records, protocol='line')
            if not response:
                self.logger.error('.write: Writing of records failed')
            else:
                self.logger.info('.write: Records written sucessfully')
```

Maybe somebody can tell where the problem is - thanks for any hints in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It lies deep in the influxdb_client package V5.3.1 (last version ever).

In this version the query goes to

```
/write
```

instead of

```
/write?db=testdb
```

After fixing this (which may break things I don't need) in the package it worked.